# callout with multiple pointers

Tags: tikz-pgf

With `tikz` is there any way of having a `callout` shape that points to more than one place?

I would like to use a `callout` shape to explain some parts of a graph. This `callout` shape would point to different elements in the graph, as the explanation is the same for a set of elements.

Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,shapes,arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm, auto]
  \node[state,initial]   (s0)               {$s_0$};
  \node[state]           (s1) [right of=s0] {$s_1$};
  \node[state,accepting] (s2) [right of=s1] {$s_2$};
  \path[->]
    (s0) edge node {a} (s1)
    (s1) edge node {c} (s2)
         edge [loop above] node {b} ();
  \node[fill=green!20, rectangle callout, callout absolute pointer={(s0.south)}]
       [below of=s0] {
         \parbox{2cm}{Each circle is a \emph{state} of the automaton}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which produces the output

[image: explaining multiple elements]

I want the `callout` pointing to all three nodes of the automaton.

Comment: MWE? Two ideas: 1. Modifiying the shape. 2. Two otherwise identical shapes overlaying but with different pointers. 3. Combination of 1. and 2.: A shape that only draws the pointers so that the overlaying would be a little bit more effective.

Comment: Why was the question down-voted?

Comment: It wasn't. It is still on +2/-0.

Comment: @mafp Downvote might be due to the missing [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) and picture image as seen in your  [Q revision history](http://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/109488/revisions). Once you posted them all is well.

Comment: @texenthusiast Click on the score: +4/-0. There is no downvote.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This updates ([→ first revision](https://tex.stackexchange.com/revisions/109506/1)) includes an improved `multiple absolute pointers` key.

The to-be-used shape is now taken from the usual `shape` key (default: rectangle). Do not use the option `rectangle callout`! It will used automatically.

The un-starred version draws an extra node (but without the pointer).
The list of multiple pointers understands now optional options that only affect the callout shape with that pointer.

This obviously doesn’t mix well with any `draw` option other than `none`.
A border that does not cross any pointers will have to be drawn manually (which is  difficult enough for the `rectangle callout` shape).

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,shapes,arrows}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  expand me/.style={#1},
  multiple absolute pointers/.style args={#1[#2]#3#4}{
    insert path={
      \foreach \qrr@tikz@calloutabsolutepointer in {#3} {
        \pgfextra
          \expandafter\pgfutil@ifnextchar\expandafter[%
          \expandafter\qrr@tikz@parse@calloutabsolutepointer\expandafter{%
          \expandafter\qrr@tikz@parse@calloutabsolutepointer\expandafter[\expandafter]\expandafter}\qrr@tikz@calloutabsolutepointer\@qrr@tikz@parse@calloutabsolutepointer
        \endpgfextra
        node[#2, shape/.expanded=\tikz@shape\space callout, expand me/.expanded=\qrr@tikz@calloutabsolutepointer@options, callout absolute pointer={(\qrr@tikz@calloutabsolutepointer@)}] {#4}
      }
      \pgfextra
        \def\pgf@tempa{#1}
        \pgfutil@in@*{#1}
        \ifpgfutil@in@\else
          \pgfkeysalso{insert path={node[#2] {#4}}}
        \fi
      \endpgfextra}}}

\def\qrr@tikz@parse@calloutabsolutepointer[#1]#2\@qrr@tikz@parse@calloutabsolutepointer{%
  \gdef\qrr@tikz@calloutabsolutepointer@options{#1}%
  \gdef\qrr@tikz@calloutabsolutepointer@{#2}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm, auto]
  \node[state,initial]   (s0)               {$s_0$};
  \node[state]           (s1) [right of=s0] {$s_1$};
  \node[state,accepting] (s2) [right of=s1] {$s_2$};
  \path[->]
    (s0) edge node {a} (s1)
    (s1) edge node {c} (s2)
         edge [loop above] node {b} ();
  \path[multiple absolute pointers={
    [fill=green!20, text width=2.1cm, below of=s0]
    {[fill=blue!20]s1.south,[fill=red!20]s2.south,[fill=yellow!60]s0.south}
    {Each circle is a \emph{state} of the automaton}
  }];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]