# Equation with explanatory boxes

Tags: tikz-pgf, equations, box, pointer

I try something like this

[image]

I wanted to adapt the following solution: [Explanatory bubbles in beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83783/explanatory-bubbles-in-beamer)

and using Ethan's answer below I managed to do this (see picture below):

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, parskip=half]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes.callouts}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,trees,positioning}  

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\marker}[1]{\tikz[baseline,remember picture] \coordinate (#1) {};}
\tikzset{mycalloutstyle/.style={
       rectangle callout, rounded corners,align=center,text
       width=1.5cm, callout absolute pointer = {#1}}}

\[ \left( {\color{blue}\marker{a}\sqrt{x-12}}+{\color{red}\marker{b}\sqrt{x}} \right)^{2} = \]% };
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw (b) ++ (-1,-1) node[mycalloutstyle={(b)++(0.4,-.1)},fill=cyan!20]{$\phantom{({\color{blue}A}+{\color{red}B})^2}$};
\draw (a) ++ (0.7,-1) node[mycalloutstyle={(a)++(.5,-.1)},fill=cyan!20,text width=2cm]{$\hspace{0.0cm}({\color{blue}A}+{\color{red}B})^2$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If there is a more elegant solution, I'm open to improvements.

Comment: I think that, despite you already accepted the answer below, you may want to look for how to use `tikzmark` library. Should be very helpful for this kind of things.

Comment: Take a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/361532/1952, It defines overlay nodes which can be used to have one node with multiple pointers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think to automatically have two pointers coming out, one would have to define a new kind of callout (and define two input coordinates for that callout).  With some manual alignment, and removing the border around the callout, it's possible to overlap two callouts so it looks one:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.callouts}

\tikzset{mycalloutstyle/.style={
       rectangle callout, rounded corners,align=center,text
       width=1cm,fill=cyan!20, callout absolute pointer = {#1}
    }
}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0)  node (myequation) {$\color{blue}(\sqrt{x-12}+1)^2$};
\draw (myequation.north) ++ (-0.5,1)node[mycalloutstyle={(myequation.north)++(-10pt,0)}]{A};
\draw (myequation.north) ++ (0.5,1)node[mycalloutstyle={(myequation.north)++(20pt,0)}]{B};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That is not the most elegant solution but it worked. I improved my own question above. Thanks.

Comment: Please, don’t use the `minimal` class, which is not meant for minimal examples, despite the name.

Answer (score 6):

A way to obtain the explanatory boxes with an `align*` environment and the `\psDefBoxNodes`: command from `pst-node`:

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pst-node}

\begin{document}

\psset{fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=PowderBlue, linecolor=PowderBlue, framearc = 0.4,linejoin=1,linewidth=0.4pt}
\begin{align*}
\psframebox{(\psDefBoxNodes{A}{A}+ \psDefBoxNodes{B}{B})^2} & =\psframebox{\vphantom{(} \psDefBoxNodes{Asq}{A ^2}} + \\[1ex]
\bigl(\psDefBoxNodes{lroot}{\sqrt{x + 4}}+ \psDefBoxNodes{one}{1\strut}\bigr)^2 & =\bigl(\psDefBoxNodes{rroot}{\sqrt{x + 4}\strut}\bigr)^2
\psline(A:bl)(lroot:tC)(A:br)\psline(B:bl)(one:tC)(B:br)
\psline(Asq:bl)(rroot:tC)(Asq:br)
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]