# Double (or multiple) callouts using Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

Using `tikz` is there a way to do a double (or even multiple) callout. Below is a MWE which demonstrates what I already have and does indeed give a desired output. What I am asking is whether there is a more elegant way to do this. [This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/109488/11162) question looks similar, but the solution seems to be based on a path.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.symbols,shapes.callouts}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\newcommand{\Callout}[1]{\tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base),inner xsep=0pt]{\node(#1){#1};}}


\begin{document}
Point to \Callout{here1} and to \Callout{here2}.

\tikz[remember picture, note/.style={rectangle callout, fill=red!30!white}]{\node [note, overlay,callout absolute pointer={(here1.south east)},text centered,below right=of here1] {Point from here};}% 
\tikz[remember picture, note/.style={rectangle callout, fill=red!30!white}]{\node [note, overlay,callout absolute pointer={(here2.south east)},text centered,below right=of here1] {Point from here};}% 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why the `$` around `\Callout`? You could put both `\node .. ;` inside the same `\tikz` environment.

Comment: @Manuel You're right! I minimised the code and forgot to remove the $. Further, I have tested now putting all into one `\tikz` and it produces the same result. It would be nice though to not need to repeat so much information within the two nodes.

Comment: The solution in linked question uses `\path` to declare the `multiple callout` but looking at the code, you'll see that it draws a callout node and adds some more paths from them.

Comment: @Ignasi Ok, I think I have something, but it doesn't point to the right positions! I pasted the appropriate code from the other question and then added: `\tikz[remember picture]{\path[multiple absolute pointers={[fill=blue!20, below right=20mm and 10mm of here1]{here1.south,here2.south}{new pointer}}];}`

Comment: @Geoff Have you considered moving the definition of the `note` style into a `\tikzset{}` in the preamble? You can add the `overlay` and `text centered` options to that style as well...

Comment: @Geoff Try with `\tikz[remember picture, overlay] ...` You need this option when making reference to nodes in other tikzpictures.

Comment: @Ignasi Bingo! It works! Many thanks. Should I delete the question as a duplicate?